# How to not display in php if the field is empty

Tags: php, function, hide

Can anyone help how to hide the field and title if the value is not there. For example if there is no Fax No., it should not show the title name "Fax:" also.

```
<?php
$name = get_sub_field('name');
$address = get_sub_field('address');
$fax = get_sub_field('fax');
?>

<div class="col-md-10">
    <h6><?php echo (isset($name)) ? $name : ''; ?></h6>
    <p>P.O. Box: <?php echo (isset($address)) ? $address : ''; ?></p>
    <p>Fax: <?php echo (isset($fax)) ? $fax : ''; ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: if(!empty($fax)) { //display fax } (depends on the return value of your function)

Comment: What does `get_sub_field` return if `fax` is not found?

Comment: Change the Fax line you have to: `<?php echo (isset($fax) ? '<p>Fax: ' . $fax . '</p>' : ''); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$name = get_sub_field('name');
$address = get_sub_field('address');
$fax = get_sub_field('fax');
?>

<div class="col-md-10">
<?php
    if(isset($name)){
?>
        <h6><?=$name ?> </h6>
<?php    
    }    
?>
 ....
</div>
```

this will work.  it looks messy though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves the problem.

```
    <?php
    $name = get_sub_field('name');
    $address = get_sub_field('address');
    $fax = get_sub_field('fax');
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-10">
    <h6><?php echo (!empty($name)) ? $name : ''; ?></h6>
    <p><?php echo (!empty($address)) ? 'P.O. Box: '.$address : ''; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo (!empty($fax)) ? 'Fax: '.$fax : ''; ?></p>
    </div>
```